# stating: google has disabled uso of the Maps api for this application

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a Google Maps application in a JSwing application using JXBrowser. I am using a API key provided by Google.

```
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserFactory;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class GAPIJXBrowser {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final Browser browser = BrowserFactory.create();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(browser.getView().getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(700, 500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            browser.executeJavaScript("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
    "<html>\n" +
    "  <head>\n" +
    "    <title>Simple Map</title>\n" +
    "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n" +
    "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
    "    <style>\n" +
    "      html, body, #map-canvas {\n" +
    "        height: 100%;\n" +
    "        margin: 0px;\n" +
    "        padding: 0px\n" +
    "      }\n" +
    "    </style>\n" +
    "    <script src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey\"></script>\n" +
    "    <script>\n" +
    "var map;\n" +
    "function initialize() {\n" +
    "  var mapOptions = {\n" +
    "    zoom: 8,\n" +
    "    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)\n" +
    "  };\n" +
    "  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),\n" +
    "      mapOptions);\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "\n" +
    "google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);\n" +
    "\n" +
    "    </script>\n" +
    "  </head>\n" +
    "  <body>\n" +
    "    <div id=\"map-canvas\"></div>\n" +
    "  </body>\n" +
    "</html>");

}
}
```

Page loads but getting the following error while executing:

```
stating : google has disabled uso of the Maps api for this application.
```

I even tried a new key.

[image]

What wrong am I doing it over here?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that you use wrong API Key. Please make sure that you [generate API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) correctly and you put it into the following line instead of the `MyKey`:

```
<script src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey\"></script>
```